# Definition of projection and orthogonality condition

Tags: linear-algebra, probability-theory, proof-verification, orthogonality

I'm confused about the definition of projection of a random variable $T$ onto a linear space $\mathcal{S}$. In order to illustrate my question I refer to van der Vaart Theorem 11.1 of the book "Asymptotic Statistics".

Consider the random variables $T,S$ where $S \in \mathcal{S}$, both defined on the same probability space, with finite second moments, and $\mathcal{S}$ is a linear space.

Suppose we show that $E(T-S)^2 \geq E(T-\hat{S})^2$ $\forall S \in \mathcal{S}$ with $\hat{S} \in \mathcal{S}$ and strict inequality iff $E(\hat{S}-S)^2\neq 0$ (this is the first part of the proof of Theorem 11.1).

Questions:

(1) I understand that  $E(T-S)^2 \geq E(T-\hat{S})^2$ $\forall S \in \mathcal{S}$ with $\hat{S} \in \mathcal{S}$ implies $ \hat{S} \in argmin_{S\in \mathcal{S}} E(T-S)^2$. Could you help me to show that $\hat{S} = argmin_{S\in \mathcal{S}} E(T-S)^2$ a.s.? In other words, why such a minimum is almost surely unique?

(2) Why does (1) imply that $\hat{S}$ is a projection of $T$ onto $\mathcal{S}$? Where can I find such a definition of projection?

(3) Where do I need the fact that $T,S$ have finite second moments and $\mathcal{S}$ is a liner space?